# C++ const iterator of array of pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, iterator

I have a problem with a `const` iterator because I try to iterate an array of 
pointers but when I try to print it, it returns the array that the first 
pointer points at. How can I fix it?

The first array is an array of `T` and the second array is an array of pointers
to the first array:

```
class const_iterator {
public:
    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    typedef T                         value_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t                 difference_type;
    typedef const T*                  pointer;
    typedef const T&                  reference;

    const_iterator() : ptr(0) { }

    const_iterator(const const_iterator &other) : ptr(other.ptr) { }

    const_iterator& operator=(const const_iterator &other) {
        ptr = other.ptr;
        return *this;
    }

    ~const_iterator() { }

    reference operator*() const {
        return *ptr;
    }

    pointer operator->() const {
        return ptr;
    }

    const_iterator operator++(int) {
        const_iterator tmp(ptr);
        ++ptr;
        return tmp;
    }

    const_iterator& operator++() {
        ++ptr;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const const_iterator &other) const {
        return other.ptr==ptr;
    }

    bool operator!=(const const_iterator &other) const {
        return other.ptr!=ptr;
    }

private:

    const T *ptr;

    friend class SortedArray; 

    const_iterator(const T*p) : ptr(p){ }

}; 

const_iterator begin() const {
    return const_iterator(*Array);
}

const_iterator end() const {
    return const_iterator(*Array+index);
}
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: This is the declaration of the array:
T* Array1;
T** Array;

Comment: You also haven't specified what `T` is or, more importantly, how `Array` and `Array1` are initialised.    Those types of information gaps would be addressed if you provided a [mcve], which is sort of necessary if you expect others to BE ABLE to help, rather than having to resort to mindreading.

Comment: T is a generic type can be everithing then the initialization is this:
Array1 = new T[dim];
Array = new T*[dim];

Comment: What I need is iterate the second array. But when i try to use iterator it return me the first array

Comment: if can help this is how i call it from the main:
for (SortedArray<int>::const_iterator it = array.begin(); it != array.end(); it++) {
    cout << *(it)<< endl;
   }